# Best way to update to newer versions of bootstrap and font awesome in blazor webassembly app

Tags: bootstrap-4, font-awesome, blazor-webassembly

Can anyone tell me the best way to update to newer versions of bootstrap and font awesome in blazor webassembly app from the default versions that are used when creating the project?

Answer (score 11):

[Libman in asp.net core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/libman/libman-vs?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

I use libman. In visual studio, delete the bootstrap folder, then right click the project -> add client side library -> chose provider cdnjs -> search twitter-bootstrap. Once you chose, click install.

This will add the files to the lib folder in wwwroot, you just need to update the link in wwwroot/index.html

Comment: That's nice, but then you rely on `cdnjs.cloudflare.com` availability. I would recommend using local (compiled) files.

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrap offers NuGet packages.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/download/

Comment: but how to reference it after installing nuget? it doent seem to work

Comment: Well, that's a very good question, still searching for it !

Answer (score 1):

1. Download Compiled CSS and JS from here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/download/
2. copy the two directories (css and js) in \wwwroot\css\bootstrap-5.0.2 (or any directory in project)
3. In your webpage/razor/Layout add `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />`